# Cakephp cannot pull associated Model details via Belongsto

Tags: php, cakephp

I have below defined in my model:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
        'GroupBuy' => array(
            'className' => 'GroupBuy',
            'foreignKey' => 'group_buy_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
```

This however does not pull details from GroupBuy nor User table but it fetches only user_id and group_buy_id which are defined in this GroupBuyUser model.

I've set recursive two with below:

```
$this->GroupBuyUser->recursive = 2;
```

Is there something wrong I'm doing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code in your `GroupBuyUser Model`:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
    ),
    'GroupBuy' => array(
        'className' => 'GroupBuy',
        'foreignKey' => 'group_buy_id'
    )
);
```

You don't need to set the recursive property to 2. This is basically used while we want to fetch result from deeper associated models.